# Is it possible to determine when an answer was accepted?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I don't see an obvious way to determine the date and time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to Loong's answer, you can also use the [timeline view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view). This has the advantage of always showing the full date and time; the tooltip uses the same relative timestamp (e.g. "yesterday", "*n* days ago") used in most other places on the site, but you can't hover over a hover text (the way you can to get the more precise time in other cases).

The information on acceptance lives on the timeline for the accepted answer; for example, on [Who played Hedwig?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105190/), the tooltip only says that the answer was accepted "two days ago":

[image]

But the [timeline of phantom42's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/105192/timeline) shows the full date and time:

[image]

This screen is a bit hard to get to; if you have [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) installed, you can use [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/a/4238) to add a link to every post<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

You can also get here from the [question's timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/105190/timeline); the time each answer was posted is recorded there, and includes a link to the answer's timeline:

[image]

You'll notice that the (currently) accepted answer is marked by a green checkmark.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that I'm using another UserScript to add a "revisions" link to each post; you don't get that for free with the script I've linked to here

Comment: This is great,  and I'm glad it wasn't something blatantly obvious.

Comment: @ThePopMachine It's really poorly-advertised; apparently it's considered a failure internally ([according to animuson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post#comment547988_126447))

Comment: I think it's awesome.   That shouldn't be considered a failure.   I would read things in this mode.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Well, I guess there was enough interest to give it a spit-shine

Answer (score 8):

Check the mouseover (tooltip) of the green *accepted* symbol.

[image]

Comment: Can't access this on a tablet...